# Зависимости таблиц node и url_alias Drupal 6

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal

Подскажите, можно ли как-то сформировать запрос, который выведет данные из таблицы node с присоединением таблицы url_alias в DRUPAL 6?

В таблице `url_alias` есть поле pid - там не ID и я не могу понять что это вообще за колонка.
Там же есть колонка `src` в которой содержится внутренний адрес страницы вида node/nid (например, node/525).
Помогите сформировать запрос в котором получить: `nid, title` из таблицы node и `dst` из таблицы url_alias

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151483/how-to-map-url-alias-table-to-node-table